# show that $A=\{f \in C^1 [0,1]\}$ is semi simple

Tags: operator-theory, banach-algebras

Let $A=C^1 ([0,1])$ with the norm
$$
\|f\|=\|f\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{\infty}, \quad f\in C^1([0,1])
$$
I want to show that $A$ is semi simple.

Recall that A is semisimple if $Rad(A)=0$ where  $Rad=\bigcap J$ s.t $J$ a maximal ideal.

To show that $Rad(A)=0$ is it enough to show $\sigma(f)={0}$?
What is the invertible set of $A$ ?

Comment: What is $\sigma(f)$ supposed to be? When you say "invertible set" do you mean the set of units of $A$, that is, the set $\{a \in A: \exists b \in A, ab=ba=1\}$?

Comment: In this algebra, units are simply the functions which don't vanish anywhere.

Comment: @krm2233 $\sigma(f)$ is  a spectrum of $f$ for all $f \in A$.

Comment: I have edited your post to try and make the mathematics display as I think you intended, but as it stands, the norm you define does not appear to be relevant -- the algebra structure, and hence the notion of an ideal and the radical of $A$, is independent of the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t \in [0,1]$ then $\text{e}_t\colon A\to \mathbb C$ given by $\text{e}_t(f) = f(t)$ is clearly a homomorphism of algebras, so that $J_t = \text{ker}(\text{e}_t)$ is an ideal in $A$. Can you use these ideals to answer your question? (If $A$ is taken to be real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ then $e_t\colon A \to \mathbb R$, but this does not change the nature of the ideals $J_t$ significantly.)

Comment: so if we let $g \in J_t$ then $\text{e}_t (g)=0$ so that  $g(x)=0$ we deduce that $ Rad(A)=0$.

Comment: If $g \in J_t$ then $e_t(g)=g(t)=0$, not $g(x)=0$.